# Consutrcting a transition diagram of a deterministic Turing machine

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I'm having some issues constructing a transition diagram of a deterministic Turing machine for $L = \{0^i1^j2^j3^k \ | \ i = j + k\}$

The point where I get stuck is how I should make sure that $i = j + k$

**My thoughts:**

My thought was to initially do something similar to do something including an addition turing machine where I check that the final tape is of the structure generated by the language i.e we should have 2 $0$s, 1 $1$, 1 $2$ and 3 $1$s = 6 and if it is correct then we'd go through checking if $0$s come before $1$s, $2$s before $1$s and $3$s before $2$s.

I think this is a really complicated way to do it, and that's why I'm asking.

**Question:** Construct a transition diagram of a deterministic Turing machine for $L = \{0^i1^j2^j3^k \ | \ i = j + k\}$. What I'm asking is for some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to give you a hint, but if you are lost, you could think about doing it in three large steps:

1. Make a single pass through, making sure that you encounter $0$s followed by $1$s followed by $2$s followed by $3$s.  You should think through the end conditions if this process goes smoothly, or what items you might encounter on the tape that could send you to a reject state.
2. Now check that there are the same number of $1$s and $2$s: go back and find the start of the $1$s.  For every $1$, replace it with an $i$, run off to the right and find a corresponding $2$ (which you must also replace with some symbol, such as $T$).  Again, think through the end conditions, and how you will know if something unexpected has happened.
3. Finally, check if $i=j+k$.  Run to the beginning of the $0$s, and for every $0$ you replacing (with, say, $o$), run off and find the next $T$ or $3$ and replace that with some other symbol ($F$?).  At the end, a pass left will be sufficient to tell you that there are no more $0$s, and a pass right will be sufficient to tell you that there are no remaining $T$s or $3$s.